# Android: how to set the chart engine title to two lines?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i am implementing Achart engine line chart. Everything is working fine. I want to set the chart title to two lines if it is big title. But there is no option given, to set it to two lines. How can i do that? Can any one of you help me?

Comment: can you put the code where you are setting titile.

Comment: renderer.setChartTitle(ElGiftoAppData.getAppData().strVendorPageProductName);
     System.out.println("Print the productname:" + ElGiftoAppData.getAppData().strVendorPageProductName);    
     renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(15);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never been in such situation but seeing you question I did some RnD on the Source code of the AChartEngine open source code.

And I found this two things :

1) in code where they set tile **[Line no 251](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/source/browse/trunk/core/src-achartengine/org/achartengine/activity/GraphicalActivity.java?r=168)**

2) and XML file for **[the same](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/source/browse/trunk/core/res/layout/xy_chart_activity.xml?r=168)**

but there is nothing which can stop the TextView to be more than single line.

I am not enough capable that I file this as bug..
But As far as I understand You will have to figur out something else for you as there is no any other option using the library for this thing.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.